# What's the code to swap variable values using AND, OR, NOT

Tags: python-3.x

I need a code to swap the value of two variables without using third variable but only with AND, OR & NOT operators

I have tried it but i always lost one value

Exact code

Comment: What exactly have you tried? I don't see any effort here.

Comment: i have tried doing it by logical operators, AND, OR, NOT

Comment: A =5
B=10
A=A AND B
 but when i am trying this i lost one value either for a or b
please help me solving this by using AND OR NOT only

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 1
b = 2

# swap
a, b = b, a
```

Answer (score 1):

For integers, you can use xor:

```
x = x ^ y
y = x ^ y
x = x ^ y
```

But otherwise you should just stick to standard swapping practice:

```
x, y = y, x
```

The code above creates the tuple `(y, x)` and unpacks it to `x` and `y`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 6
>>> a+=b
>>> b = a - b
>>> a = a - b
>>> a
6
>>> b
5
>>>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

As the pythonic approach and the arithmetic approach have already been submitted as answers, I will present the `bitwise xor` approach, [as outlined on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm):

```
a = a ^ b
b = b ^ a
a = a ^ b
```

Of course, you can simplify that if you want:

```
a ^= b
b ^= a
a ^= b
```

---

It's really important to note that this only works on things that can be represented bitwise, like integers. Python will raise an error if you try it on floats or strings or most other datatypes.